# Query optimization: 1800 queries -> 50

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm querying a postgresql database which holds an agenda-table:

```
agenda |> id (int) | start (timestamp) | end (timestamp) | facname | .....
```

I want to make a kind of summary of one day in the form of a 'timeline' consisting of a small picture for every 15 minutes interval: on / off according to the availability of the facility.

Now is it relatively simple to query the database for every 15 minutes and check if a reservation is present and change the img source.

But if you want to make an overview of 10 days and 5 different facilities you'll end up querying the database

```
10(days) * 36(quaters a day) * 5 (facilities) = 1800 database querys/page load.
```

So this results in a very heavy pay load.

Is there a way I can reduce the amount of queries and so the payload?

Comment: You can group the sum of the events every 15 min with a single query. I meen, you can grab the data for the whole day with a single select, and each row to be a quarter_hour

Comment: not sure if this helps you, but this query will generate a list of times with 15 minute interval `SELECT * FROM generate_series('2008-03-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2008-03-10 24:00'::timestamp, '15 minutes');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, I think we may first find a way to, given a timestamp, find in which quarter of an hour it belongs to. For instance, the hour `08:38` belongs to quarter `08:30`, the `08:51` to `08:45`, and so on.

To do that, we can use a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION date_trunc_quarter(timestamp )
RETURNS TIMESTAMP
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
SELECT * FROM
        generate_series(
                date_trunc('hour',$1),
                date_trunc('hour',$1)+interval '1hour',
                interval '15min'
        ) AS gen(quarter)
WHERE gen.quarter < $1
ORDER BY gen.quarter
DESC LIMIT 1
$$;
```

It uses the `generate_series` function to generate all the four quarters (e.g. 08:00, 08:15, 08:30 and 08:45) within the same hour as the given timestamp (e.g. 08:38), do get the given hour it uses the well-known `date_trunc` function. Then, it filters only the quarters which is smaller then the given timestamp, sort it and get the bigger one. As it is always only four values at most, sorting it is not a big issue.

Now, with that you can easily query like this:

```
SELECT date_trunc_quarter(tstart) AS quarter, count(*)
FROM agenda
GROUP BY quarter
ORDER BY quarter;
```

I think it is fast enough, and to make it even faster, you can create an expression index on agenda:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_agenda_quarter ON agenda ((date_trunc_quarter(tstart)));
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2a3cc/1) with a self-contained test case of it all.

Comment: Wow. Thankyou! just a couple of questions: 1-What happens with events spanning multiple intervals/hours. 2-HOw can I add this function standard to my database? When adding it in the sql pane it says column t not found...